# Can I tell TeXcount to not count underscores as word separators?

Tags: texcount

I am trying to count words in a document that contains various C types such as `\texttt{uintptr\_t}`, `\texttt{size\_t}`, etc. However, when I use texcount it breaks at the underscore and these as two words.

Is there a way to tell texcount to treat words with underscores as being only one word?

If I run texcount on this file it reports 5 words:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Word with underscore: \texttt{uintptr\_t}.
\end{document}
```

How can I work around this and count `uintptr\_t` as one word?

edit: I've tried the following which mostly works:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
%TC:newcounter icode Number of words in code
%TC:newcounter icodeuses Number of code uses
%TC:macrocount \code [icodeuses]
%TC:macro \code [icode]
\newcommand*{\code}[1]{\texttt{#1}}
\begin{document}
Word with underscore: \code{uintptr\_t}.
\end{document}
```

This now reports the following for `texcount -sum`:

```
Sum count: 6
Words in text: 3
Words in headers: 0
Words outside text (captions, etc.): 0
Number of headers: 0
Number of floats/tables/figures: 0
Number of math inlines: 0
Number of math displayed: 0
Number of words in code: 2
Number of code uses: 1
```

Can I exclude certain counters from the total sum?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se, and thanks for providing a minimal example. I don't think there's a way to do this with a command line option passed to `texcount` but you could modify the script itself to do this.

Comment: I had a look at the source but unfortunately I don't speak enough perl to fix this. However, I think I found a reasonable workaround using the `-template=` flag and bash: `echo "Total words: $(($(texcount '-template={w} + {icodeuses}' foo.tex)))"` prints `Total words: 4`

Comment: In Linux you can also first remove the `\_` from your file with `sed` and then count: `sed "s/\\\_//g" yourfile.tex|texcount -`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no simple way to do this with a command line option, but it's easy to add `\_` to the list of character modifiers.

Make a copy of `texcount.pl` and place it somewhere where it will be found (your local `~/bin` folder is an obvious choice). It's probably best to give it a different name so as not to override the standard one. (This assumes Mac/Linux; I don't have any idea about how to do this in Windows.)

On line 494 you should find the following line:

```
my $modifiedchars='\\\\[\'\"\`\~\^\=](@|\{@\})';
```

Change this to:

```
my $modifiedchars='\\\\[\'\"\`\~\^\=\_](@|\{@\})';
```

This will now include `\_` as  character modifier.

Now running this modified file with your example yields:

```
$ ./texcount-new.pl  -sum word-count-underscore.tex
File: word-count-underscore.tex
Encoding: ascii
Sum count: 5
Words in text: 3
Words in headers: 0
Words outside text (captions, etc.): 0
Number of headers: 0
Number of floats/tables/figures: 0
Number of math inlines: 0
Number of math displayed: 0
Number of words in code: 1
Number of code uses: 1
```